# Função JavaScript que complete o campo com zeros à esquerda

Tags: javascript

Possuo um campo que aceita 4 dígitos, eu gostaria que, após o preenchimento do campo, ao mudar para outro campo, caso os 4 dígitos não forem digitados, que o campo seja auto completado com zeros à esquerda.

Como ficaria uma função em JavaScript? E como chamá-la dentro do TextBox abaixo?

Campo:

```xml
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtAgencia" runat="server" Width="80px" MaxLength="4" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" onblur="caractNaoPermit(this, 'numeric'); formatCamp(this,'numeric');" onkeypress="return(validaConteudo(event, this, 'numeric'))" onfocus="removeCaracs(this,'numeric')" />&nbsp;
```

<kbd>[image: txtAgencia]</kbd>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Uma solução simples de uma única linha:

```
("0000" + n).slice(-4)
```

onde `n` é seu número:

```
("0000" + 1).slice(-4); // "0001"
("0000" + 12).slice(-4); // "0012"
("0000" + 123).slice(-4); // "0123"
("0000" + 1234).slice(-4); // "1234"
```

Para fazer funcionar em um input text, usando jquery:

```
<input id="campo_01" type="text">
<script>
    $("#campo_01").keyup(function() {
        this.value = ("0000" + this.value).slice(-4)
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma função chamada `leftPad`, para preencher os valores a esquerda do `value` passado, usando o `totalWidth` para delimitar até quanto deve se preencher e usando o `paddingChar` para dizer qual é o caracter usado. Eu coloquei por padrão o `paddingChar` como `0`.

```
function leftPad(value, totalWidth, paddingChar) {
  var length = totalWidth - value.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(length).join(paddingChar || '0') + value;
};

leftPad(1, 4); // 0001
leftPad(12, 4); // 0012
leftPad(123, 4); // 0123
leftPad(1234, 4); // 1234
leftPad(12345, 4); // 12345
```